# Find the value of $\frac{\sin 24x}{\cos18x \cos 6x}$.

Tags: trigonometry, radicals, fractions

Given  $\tan x = \sqrt{5} - 2 $, find the value of $$\frac{\sin 24x}{\cos 18x\cos 6x}.$$

Now I wrote numerator as $\sin (18 + 6)x$ and I used identity $\sin(A+B)$, after that I reduced problem to $\tan 18x + \tan 6x$

How do I proceed?
Thanks

Comment: solve the equation $$\tan(x)=\sqrt{5}-2$$

Comment: Actually you can just compute using $\tan(A+B)=(\tan(A)+\tan(B))/(1-\tan(A)\tan(B))$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have

\begin{align}
\tan 2x&=\frac{2\tan x}{1-\tan^2x}\\
&=\frac{2(\sqrt{5}-2)}{1-(\sqrt{5}-2)^2}\\
&=\frac{2(\sqrt{5}-2)}{1-5+4\sqrt{5}-4}\\
&=\frac{2(\sqrt{5}-2)}{4(\sqrt{5}-2)}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}
\end{align}

Then use

$$\tan 3A=\frac{3\tan A-\tan^3A}{1-3\tan^2A}$$

to deduce that

$$\tan 6x=\frac{11}{2}$$

Use it once again to deduce that

$$\tan18x=\frac{1199}{718}$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\tan2x=\frac{2(\sqrt5-2)}{1-(\sqrt5-2)^2}=\frac{1}{2},$$
which gives $$\sin4x=\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{4}}=\frac{4}{5}.$$

Comment: How to utilize the value of $\sin4x?$

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee By the same way we can get $\cos4x=\frac{3}{5}$ and from here we can get $\sin12x$ and $\cos12x$ and since $\cos18x\cos6x=\frac{1}{2}\left(\cos24x+\cos12x\right)$, we are done!

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

$$\tan (2x)=2\frac{\sqrt {5}-2}{4\sqrt {5}-8}=\frac {1}{2} $$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Let us try to rationalize

$$(\tan x+2)^2=5$$

$$\iff\tan^2x-4\tan x-1=0\iff1=2\cdot\dfrac{2\tan x}{1-\tan^2x}=2\tan2x$$